# jQuery navigation menu issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, navigation

I have a demo [up here](http://finite-element.com/nathanmarks/) so you can look at all the html and javascript involved.

**Problem:**

The problem I'm having is that at the moment, when you hover over a link (other than home) and then move the mouse anywhere else on the screen (except over the home link) the home link isn't reverting to the white text color.

I tried to resolve the problem by changing the following piece of code (look in the "example.js" file linked to from the page to view full code):

```
if (status == "off")
{
$(this).stop().animate({ color: linkcol },500);
}
```

I added an extra line

```
if (status == "off")
{
$(this).stop().animate({ color: linkcol },500);
$(".current_page_item_two a").stop().animate({ color: whitecol },500);
}
```

This line was intended to set the link inside the current_page_item_two element back to white when no link is hovered over (when the slider returns to the home link).

However, looking at the demo [here](http://finite-element.com/nathanmarks2/), you can see that this creates some horrible glitches in the nav (wiggle the mouse about over the links to see what I mean, I end up causing some issue where the white rollover animations don't work at all)

Also, as a side note, why are my callback functions when animating the hover rectangle being called before the animation is complete? I'm new to jquery and I was under the impression that the fourth parameter was a function to be called when the animation was complete.

Thanks!

Comment: As a side note, StackOverflow supports Markdown, which formats text without the need of ugly HTML tags and character codes. I reformatted your question to that effect.

Comment: Thanks! I'll remember that for next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is needlessly complex.  I refactored what you want to do into a very simple jQuery plugin.  If you want I encourage you to look into css3 animations to make it even smaller (although you might want to maintain cross browser compat).  The code is still a little more complex than it needs to be, although that is more due to me not having much time at the moment.  You can see the solution here:

http://jsfiddle.net/hGm7M/3/

**Edit: updated url to add resetting slider to home and changing slider width**

If you have any questions feel free to ask.

Notes:

- You could move all the css into the jQuery plugin making it a self contained widget
- You could separate the slider from the color system, although in this case I am not sure if it's worth it
- Right now I don't set the colours in css for simplicity which means browsers without javascript will just get default coloured links.  There are a number of solutions to this, but it depends on what you want to do.  I tend to prefer the widget style of things, so I would serve a html menu to the client and then **replace** it with a js widget with all its own styling et all.  This way you have graceful degradation, but the code is still simple and strait-forward.

Comment: Wait, I just realized I don't have it defaulting back to the home link.  Fixing that right now.

Comment: Thanks Carl! You have been extremely useful and in addition to helping me fix my problem I've learned some things in the process.

Comment: Glad I was able to help!  Cheers